# Equivalent of __LINE__ macro relative to beginning of function

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In C/C++, is there a macro that would tell me a line number relative to the beginning of the function in which the macro is found, rather than relative to the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can do something somewhat equivalent by creating a line offset:

```
int func(char *s)
{   static const int begin_line = __LINE__;
    #define func_line (__LINE__ - begin_line)
    /* ... */
    printf("%s():%d\n", __func__, func_line);
}
```

Output:

> func():3

Note that `begin_line` being placed on the same line as the bracket is important. If you want zero-based line indexes then feel free to add a newline.

In C++ you can use `constexpr` instead of `static const` for compile-time evaluation of `begin_line`.